# Can I develop Java Enterprise application in IntelliJ Community Edition?

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I want to develop application in Java Enterprise and Google Web Tool using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition. Is it possible? Or I have to Buy Ultimate Edition.

Comment: My recollection was that the community edition was not suitable for J2EE development.  I recommend that you buy it.  You can reuse the license if you switch machines.

Comment: You can use it without a problem. The IDE just doesn't offer any support for all things that are Java EE-related. Also, no Javascript support.

Comment: I was using eclipse but 2 years ago I bought Intellij Idea Ultimate I never been satisfied by a software purchase.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to write J2EE/GWT code, compile it and unit test it in IntelliJ Community. But you won't be able to run and debug it in the editor. You will need to use the command line and/or third party scripts and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a global library for your application server jars and add it to module dependencies.

Use this url: http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html